# How to access an object within another class (Java)

Tags: java, swing

Here's an abrevated version of what my code looks like:

```
public class ColorFactory extends JFrame {
            public ColorFactory(){
                buildTopPanel();
            }

            public void buildTopPanel(){
            JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
            this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            }

}
```

As you can see I have a method that makes a new JPanel object when called. How can I access that particular JPanel object from another class? I have a button listener class that I want to change the color of the JPanel from outside the ColorFactory class. This code is right after the ColorFactory class.

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //Change JPanel color here. 
     }
}
```

Would it be better just to instantiate JPanel in the ColorFactory constructor and then just access it through there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a design issue; in general, this type of situations require more investigation to understand how to end up with a clean and maintainable design.
However, For the specific problem you are reporting, I would:

1. Create a constructor of `ButtonListener` that receives a parameter (i.e. the `ColorFactory`) which could access the information you need, so that you can initialize a field in `ButtonListener` itself
2. Create a method `changeColor` in the `ColorFactory`. This method actually applies the color change
3. In the `ButtonListener`, invoke `changeColor` on the field, i.e. the reference to the `ColorFactory`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to make the JPanel a field in ColorFactory, so references to it don't disappear when you exit buildTopPanel().  Once you've saved a reference to it, then you have a couple of choices.  From the design standpoint, the bad choice is to expose it, e.g.:

```
JPanel getTopPanel(){
    return topPanel;
}
```

The better choice is to have your action listener send a message to `ColorFactory` that says "respondToButton(Color newColor)", and have `ColorFactory` decide to change topPanel's color... e.g.:

```
public void respondToButton(Color newColor){     
    topPanel.setBackground(newColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the JPanel a field of the class like this:

```
public class ColorFactory extends JFrame {

        JPanel topPanel;


        public ColorFactory(){
            buildTopPanel();
        }

        public void buildTopPanel(){
            topPanel = new JPanel();
            this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

        public void changeColor(Color color) {
            //color changing code here
        }


}
```

now You can get the JPanel from another class.
All you have to do now, is get the `ColorFactory` into your Button listener:

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    ColorFactory colorFactory;
    public ButtonListener(ColorFactory colorFactory) {
        this.colorFactory = colorFactory;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           colorFactory.changeColor(/* color here */);
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly discourage accessing the top panel from a listener. One could break everything by misusing the panel in a dependent (component) class. A panel should manage itself and expose methods, to which it can react according to its current state.